# How to reload add-on during development?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am developing an add-on for a Google Form. After I have made changes to the source code, how can I get the latest version of the add-on running in my Google Form? I have tried reloading the Google Form, I still have an older version of the add-on showing up.

Also, when I create a second Google Form, I don't see how to add my add-on under development (not published yet) to the form. When I got to `Tools > Script Editor`, I don't see my add-on project under "Open a recent project", but I can see it in my Google Drive.

Comment: Refer this [add-on documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish#unpublish_your_add-on).

Comment: @user1989 Thanks. The link does not match what I actuallly see in Script Editor. For example, I cannot publish my add-on as a Form add-on.

Comment: Well, you have to apply for publishing your add-on. You will have to fill out [the form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish#apply_to_publish) and submit it.

Answer (score 1):

In the "Publish" menu, choose "Deploy as add-on . . "  A dialog box will pop-up.  Fill in all the required information, then click "Update Webstore Draft".  You will be taken to the "Developer Dashboard" **IF** you have payed the $5 dollars to get your Add-on published.

You can publish your Add-on privately to "Testers".